# Removing `border` attribute from table doesn't remove the border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Why when doing `removeAttr("border")` the border is not removed (the attribute is removed, but the style remains)?

> [image]

### Demo

```js
$("#button1").on("click", function() {
  $("table").removeAttr("border");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Not</td>
      <td>Initially</td>
      <td>Bordered</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id="button1" value="Click to remove border via JavaScript">
```

I reproduced this on Chrome and Chromium.

Comment: That is because a default table without any attributes or user css styling will take up the user-agent styles i.e. browser styles. Create a simple table undecorated and see what happens.

Comment: and instead of removing the border now do a `$("table").attr("border", "0");` and then see.

Comment: @abhitalks No, a default table doesn't have any borders unless `border="1"` is added (see the first table). The second table doesn't have any borders.

Comment: Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Lqj2qcjs/

Comment: @abhitalks `attr("border", "0")` fixes the problem, but it doesn't explain why `removeAttr` doesn't work as supposed.

Comment: Another day, another Chrome idiosyncrasy. Cannot reproduce this in any other browser.

Comment: @IonicăBizău: yes.. it is really strange.. i am looking at chrome dev tools it still shows user-agent style applied.

Comment: @BoltClock Safari also does this.

Comment: @Ruddy: Ah, so WebKit/Blink then.

Comment: In fact as I am seeing it now, IE11 does not apply its styling at all!

Comment: It works beautifull in IE. So must be a webkit problem then.

Comment: Actually, it does not _not remove_ the border, it changes it to 3px something. Strange indeed.

Comment: @SalmanA My theory is that when you set `border="1"`, it sets the color, style **and size**. When you remove the property, it removes **only** the size. Since the defined behavior is to set a default value for missing values, Chrome sets it to 3px. Since it didn't removed the color and style, it keeps showing the border.

Comment: The Stack snippet works as intended... at least in firefox.

Comment: @Bakuriu This behavior is specific to webkit/blink. Firefox (which uses gecko), Opera 12.17 and below (which uses Presto) and IE (which uses (or used?) trident) will behave correctly. This means that Chrome/Chromium, Safari, Opera 15+ and other webkit/blink browsers will have the referred behavior.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not just the `border` attribute on the element itself you have to worry about.

Every browser comes with a 'default stylesheet` that will configure a base presentation for common HTML elements.  Tables are one of those elements that need to have a style set by the site in order to override this "base style" from the browser.  Browsers implement this to improve default readability on websites, but it also introduces a device which web developers must be aware of when generating their own stylesheets.

Setting the following rules:

```
table {
  border: none;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Will solve this problem for you.

jQuery can remove the attribute, but it won't trigger a redraw of the element when it's removed as opposed to updated. Since there is no overriding style element on the default CSS, the initial style is preserved.

After setting the attribute, you could always clone and re-apply (or simply re-insert the element via something silly like `$('table').appendTo($('table').parent());` to see the desired behavior as well.

---

## Edit:

**Congratulations, you found a Chrome bug**

The CSS renderer is still respecting the border attribute even after it's being removed.  It shouldn't be.  Other browsers, when running the fiddle supplied in the comments, will appropriately remove the border on the element.

***However!*** in Chrome you'll notice this little sucker hanging out on your table with a set border attribute:

[image: note the table[Attributes Style]]

*Note the* `table[Attributes Style]` *empty selector here*

Chrome is rendering this table as if it were written this way in your HTML: `<table border></table>` despite that not reflecting the information in the DOM.

You should definitely submit this to the **[Chromium Issues List](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list)**

**Check Ismael Miguel's comment below for further explanation, copied here**

> What I can think of is that Chrome has a bug related to the handling
> of the border attribute (which is deprecated, unsupported in html5).
> This might happen because the border attribute isn't linked to the
> **whole** CSS style. One example is the value property. When you run
> element.value=5;, the value attribute will remain the same, but when
> you put value="6", running element.value will return 6. This
> relationship might be broken: with the border attribute it sets the
> color **AND the border size**. When you remove the attribute, it **removes
> the size** only.

Congrats!

Comment: Why does the second table not have any default borders then?

Comment: @BoltClock – Check the second part of the comment.  There aren't any borders on the second table because he initially set it to `border=0` (implicitly) on the element.  When he removed the attribute via jQuery, the table had already been rendered without borders.  Removing the attribute itself isn't triggering a redraw of the element like adding a CSS rule would.

Comment: So then what about http://jsfiddle.net/Lqj2qcjs/3/ I set border to 0 initially then remove it via jquery and yet there is a border lol

Comment: @Huangism - Wow, that's new to me.  It appears the existence of a border attribute is enough to trigger borders being rendered.  I'll update my answer with what I can see here.

Comment: @JoshBurgess well not exactly, if you comment out the jquery line then it works as expected

Comment: @Josh Burgess: The attribute is never implicitly set. `$('table:nth-of-type(2)').attr('border')` returns undefined. So there is no attribute to be removed in the first place. But now I'm more interested in the repainting part: why would it trigger a repaint in other browsers but not Chrome? Is this part of Chrome's weird habit of not triggering repaints like other browsers do?

Comment: I looked in the Chrome UA stylesheet and could not find any styles that enable visible borders on table elements by default. In particular, setting `border: none` here is redundant because the default stylesheet does not set a border-style, leaving it the initial value of none to begin with.

Comment: @BoltClock – Right, so I kept digging, and found some bizarre behaviors in the Web Inspector.  There's a `table[Style Attribute]` that's left vestigially after the attribute is removed.

Comment: @JoshBurgess What I can think of is that Chrome has a bug related to the handling of the `border` attribute (which is deprecated, unsupported in html5). This might happen because the `border` attribute isn't linked to the **whole** CSS style. One example is the `value` property. When you run `element.value=5;`, the `value` attribute will remain the same, but when you put `value="6"`, running `element.value` will return `6`. This relationship might be broken: with the `border` attribute it sets the color **AND the border size**. When you remove the attribute, it **removes the size** only.

Comment: @JoshBurgess This behaviour, even though that is completely absurd, is valid (**in my opinion**). The border attribute only sets **the size in pixels**. (Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#attr-border). This means that removing the attribute, internally, only removes the border size. If you check the `Computed` tab on the element inspector, you will find this: `border-[top|bottom|left|right]-width: 3px;`. Removing the attribute only removed the value you have set. Since the defined behavior is to use a default value when none is present, Chrome uses 3px.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
.attr("border", "")
```

Here is an example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tw18aub3/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Tables have borders by default in some browsers, so you might want to set border to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table").attr("border", "0");
```

will do the trick